# Foreign key constraint unavailable in DDL Script generated by enterprise architect

Tags: database, database-design, database-connection, enterprise-architect

Modeled numerous tables for a database. Each table has got its primary key and Foreign Key(s). But when i'm generating DDL scripts for the tables, foreign key constraints are unavailable even if model diagram shows constraints it has.

As its solution i've already tried out all those check marks available we could use while generating DDL.
What i believe i must have left any other configuration or followed incorrect sequence of steps for the same.

Possibles solutions will be welcomed. Else i will have to add constraints manually which shouldn't be the standard if you're using a dedicated tool.
**See the images for more clarification**

[image: Carefully observe no foreign key constraint generated]

[image: Diagram shows it has foreign key constraints for the table]

[image: Options i've tried]

[image]

Comment: I'm not following the DDL questions currently as I have no need for DDL generation. You should probably cross post on Sparx' forum (with link to this thread to include the pictures) if you have not already done so.

Comment: Also, look at the end of the DDL file. FK's are usually generated last to ensure that both tables involved have been created. For instance if table Question is generated, you can't generate its two FK's until the tables they reference have been created. Working out the full dependency tree for FK dependencies can be complicated so they're ususlly left until after all tables are generated.

Comment: @simonatrcl i was also thinking the same but wasn't sure. So does it means tool has been kept deprived off this functionality i.e. generating foreign keys in DDL??

Comment: NO - it just means that usually they make generating the DDL script easier by only putting in FK definitions after all the create table's have been done.

Comment: @simonatrcl ok . I'll really be grateful to you if you could give me an example generating FK in DDL through the tool.

Comment: @codechefvaibhavkashyap have you tried generating the whole database? If I understand Simon correctly the FK will only be generated if both tables are being generated. So generating for a single table will never generate FK's (unless it is a FK to itself)

Comment: @GeertBellekens yup, i tried generating DDL for each table after i completed the whole design but none of the FK(s) were generated. There must be some loop whole in my approach. If you could help that will be great.

Comment: Do you mean you generated the dll for each table individually, or for the whole database at once? Both approaches may lead to different results. If none of that works you can try to reverse engineer a simple example and see how that looks in EA. Look for any differences between the FK you create and try to generate and the FK's that are being reverse engineered.